# MATLAB: "Not enough input arguments" error

Tags: matlab

I have two simple functions in two separate files like below:

```
function [thetavals postvals] = opt_compute_posterior(joint, theta_min, theta_max, num_steps)
    thetavals = linspace(theta_min, theta_max, num_steps); 
    postvals = joint(thetavals);
    postvals = postvals / ( sum(postvals) .* ( (theta_max - theta_min)/num_steps ));
end

function joint = plJoint(tobs) 
    gamma = 2.43; 
    joint = @(theta)( ( 1 ./ (theta.^(gamma + 1)) ) .* (tobs < theta) );

end
```

When I test this code with 
`opt_compute_posterior(plJoint, 0, 300, 1000)`, I have error of "Not enough input arguments.", and I cannot find where the hell is wrong with the codes. Please lit me a light.

Comment: What does `which opt_compute_posterior` return?

Comment: @hbaderts It returns thetavals and postvals, which are some intervals and Riemann approximation of the joint function

Comment: As per the error message, you don't have enough input arguments.  You need `opt_compute_posterior(plJoint(you_need_an_input_here), 0, 300, 1000)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass `plJoint` as a function handle to `opt_compute_posterior`. But if you just write `plJoint`, MATLAB interprets that as a function call and treats it as if you had written `plJoint()`. To indicate that you want a function handle, you need the `@` symbol:

```
opt_compute_posterior(@plJoint, 0, 300, 1000)
```

EDIT:

It seems I had mistaken the intent of the original code. `plJoint` already returns a function handle, and you did intend to call it from the command window. In that case, you need to pass it a value for `tobs` when you call it, i.e.

```
opt_compute_posterior(plJoint(0.1), 0, 300, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I surely want to pass plJoint as a function handle. However, if I type opt_compute_posterior(@plJoint, 0, 300, 1000), "postvals" is assigned to a function handle, not the calculated result of the anonymous function inside plJoint, and thus results error of "Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'". How can I fix this?

Comment: Ahhh... I see, you're returning a function handle in the `plJoint` function. Nevermind my initial answer then; you need to pass `plJoint` a value for `tobs` when you call it.